# How to count the number of loops in c# (goto loops)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity

I have created a quiz program which goes through 5 questions. If you get a question wrong you are forced to start again from the beginning, I added this loop by 
placing the code `goto start;` and placed `start:` where I wanted it to loop from.

My question is: I want to add a part at the end where it says how many times the program was looped so I can add a writeline saying "well done you took X times to complete the quiz"

here is the main part of the program:(without the namespaces and using statements)

```
        /*----------------------------------------Declaration----------------------------------------- */

        string q1, q2, q3, q4, q5;

        /*----------------------------------------TITLE----------------------------------------- */

        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the Ultimate quiz!");
        Console.WriteLine();

        /*----------------------------------------QUESTION 1----------------------------------------- */
        start:
        Console.WriteLine("The JavaScript Language is not object oriented (True/False)");
        Console.WriteLine();
        q1 = Console.ReadLine();
        q1 = q1.ToUpper();

        if (q1 == "TRUE")
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Well Done, you may move on to the next question");
        }

        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sorry you got the answer wrong, you have to start again");
            goto start;
        }

        Console.WriteLine();

        /*----------------------------------------QUESTION 2----------------------------------------- */

        Console.WriteLine("What is the age range to qualify for an apprenticeship in the uk? Please type in the following format xx-yy");
        Console.WriteLine();
        q2 = Console.ReadLine();

        if (q2 == "16-24")
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Well Done, you may move on to the next question");
        }

        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sorry you got the answer wrong, you have to start again");
            goto start;
        }

        Console.WriteLine();

        /*----------------------------------------QUESTION 3----------------------------------------- */

        Console.WriteLine("Is HTML a programming language (Yes or No)");
        Console.WriteLine();
        q3 = Console.ReadLine();
        q3 = q3.ToUpper();

        if (q3 == "NO")
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Well Done, you may move on to the next question");
        }

        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sorry you got the answer wrong, you have to start again");
            goto start;
        }

        Console.WriteLine();

        /*----------------------------------------QUESTION 4----------------------------------------- */
        Console.WriteLine("In JavaScript, What are the 2 charecters used to symbolise a single line comment?");
        Console.WriteLine();
        q4 = Console.ReadLine();

        if (q4 == "//")
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Well Done, you may move on to the next question");
        }

        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sorry you got the answer wrong, you have to start again");
            goto start;
        }

        Console.WriteLine();

        /*----------------------------------------QUESTION 5----------------------------------------- */
        Console.WriteLine("500 < 600 && 700 < 600");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Is the above statement true or false ?");
        Console.WriteLine();
        q5 = Console.ReadLine();
        q5 = q5.ToUpper();

        if (q5 == "FALSE")
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Well Done, you may move on to the next question");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Congratulations You have passed the quiz!");
        }

        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sorry you got the answer wrong, you have to start again");
            goto start;
        }

        Console.WriteLine();


        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using `goto`?

Comment: I am an apprentice and learning c#. i saw a video on YouTube using this loop but I was advised by my boss that its quite old code and I should organise it into methods to wrap them haven't got that far yet

Comment: You might find it easier if you find a different learning tool. `goto` can make you code hard to follow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add three line in your code -->

1. Before Start: --> `int count = 0;`
2. After Start: --> `count++;`
3. Last line of your code. -->

   Console.WriteLine("well done you took " + count +  " times to complete the quiz");

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so you might already have your answer, and this is a solution too BUT (and i hope you don't take this as a negative thing) i remade the whole thing, to me at least it is simpler and less line consuming (at least i think so)

```
            string q;
            int retryCount = 1;

            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the Ultimate quiz!");
            Console.WriteLine();

            start:
            const int numberOfQuestions = 5;
            for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfQuestions; i++) {
                if (i > 1) {Console.WriteLine();}
                switch (i) {
                    case 1:
                        Console.WriteLine("The JavaScript Language is not object oriented (True/False)");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Console.WriteLine("What is the age range to qualify for an apprenticeship in the uk? Please type in the following format xx-yy");
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        Console.WriteLine("Is HTML a programming language (Yes or No)");
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        Console.WriteLine("In JavaScript, What are the 2 charecters used to symbolise a single line comment?");
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        Console.WriteLine("500 < 600 && 700 < 600");
                        Console.WriteLine();
                        Console.WriteLine("Is the above statement true or false ?");
                        break;
                }

                Console.WriteLine();
                q = Console.ReadLine();
                q = q.ToUpper();

                switch (i) {
                    case 1:
                        if (q == "TRUE") {
                            Console.WriteLine();
                            Console.WriteLine("Well Done, you may move on to the next question");
                        } else {  goto restart; }
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        if (q == "16-24") {
                            Console.WriteLine();
                            Console.WriteLine("Well Done, you may move on to the next question");
                        } else { goto restart; }
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        if (q == "NO") {
                            Console.WriteLine();
                            Console.WriteLine("Well Done, you may move on to the next question");
                        } else { goto restart; }
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        if (q == "//") {
                            Console.WriteLine();
                            Console.WriteLine("Well Done, you may move on to the next question");
                        } else { goto restart; }
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        if (q == "FALSE") {
                            Console.WriteLine();
                            goto end;
                        } else { goto restart; }
                        break;
                }
            }

            restart:
            Console.WriteLine("Sorry you got the answer wrong, you have to start again");
            retryCount += 1;
            goto start;


            end:
            Console.WriteLine("Congratulations You have passed the quiz!");
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Well done!, you took {0} times to complete the quiz.", retryCount));
            Console.ReadKey();
```

I hope this is what you were trying to acheive and you don't need to use all the code, was just showing you dont need to create q1,q2,q3 etc....

just add more cases at will.

Comment: I wanted to collapse it further and have a dictionary of questions and answers and make it do them in random order, allow 1 wrong of n etc etc....

Comment: In that case, i'd go for foreach and not a switch.
if that dictionary has propretys its "easy"

Answer (score 0):

declare

```
int count = 0;
```

at the begginging and everytime someone fails send them to `repeat`:

```
repeat:
count++;
goto start;
```

Like this:

```
void a() {
                string q, q1;
                int count = 0;
            start:
                int a = 2;
                if (a != 3) goto repeat;
                else goto end;

            repeat:
                count++;
                goto start;

            end:
                string congrats = "you have repeated: " + count.ToString() + "times!";

            }
```

Comment: when i added the counter with count++; it said unreachable local variable

Comment: What is "it" and what *exactly* did it say?

Comment: there I update a code. Copy the structure and it should work for you

Answer (score 0):

put

```
count++
```

in the loop you want to know the number of loops it went, then for example if you want to check if the loop have gone 15 then

```
if(count = 15)
```

then add your code

Answer (score 0):

Though others have answered the specific `goto` question I want to offer a way without using gotos, which might prove better in the long run if you want to count things while you loop.

Add a count:

```
    string q1, q2, q3, q4, q5;
    int count = 0;
```

Then let's use a `while` loop.

```
    /*------------------------------QUESTION 1-------------------------------- */
    while (true)
    {
        ++count;
        Console.WriteLine("The JavaScript Language is not object oriented (True/False)");

        //... other questions as they were....
        // with one small change e.g.
        if (q1 == "TRUE")
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Well Done, you may move on to the next question");
        }
       else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sorry you got the answer wrong, you have to start again");
            continue; // <-----------instead of goto start;
        }

        //... other questions as they were....
        //with one small change

       if (q5 == "FALSE")
       {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Well Done, you may move on to the next question");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Congratulations You have passed the quiz!");
            break; //<--------- if they get the final question right,
                   // break out of the while loop
       }


    } //<- end of while loop

    //Output message you suggested
    Console.WriteLine("You took {0} attempts", count);
```

Realistically, the goto and while/continue/break have the same effect, but give the program a bit more structure.

If you want to give them a maximum number of tries you can start considering using a `for` loop instead.